# Bootstrap video player

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want a responsive bootstrap video player and demo so that I know it will work responsively. presently I am using http://html5-ninja.com/preview/index/5#.UYjKBbWouuY but it doesn't support ie8 and not able to responsive.

I have used it like:

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="background: wheat">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="videoUiWrapper thumbnail">
            <video width="640" height="360" id="vdHotPress">
                <source src="http://ia700305.us.archive.org/18/items/CopyingIsNotTheft/CINT_Nik_H264_720.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
                <source src="http://ia700305.us.archive.org/18/items/CopyingIsNotTheft/CINT_Nik_H264_720_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it's not showing the play n volume buttons image. And also not responsive I mean I have checked with mozilla and attaching the screenshot.
So that you can have an idea.
[image: Desktop version]

[image: Mobile version]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you set the width manually but on mobile the width do not exceed 480px for iPhone for example:

So you use bootstrap for responsiveness

```
<div class="col-md-8" ...>
```

This will take automatically the good width relative on screen size
so you just need to tell to your video to take the full width it needs by:

```
<video width="100%" ...>
```

And if you want to add controls buttons on your player you just need to add `controls` as an attribute:

```
<video width="100%" id="vdHotPress" controls>
```

Code be like:

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="background: wheat">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="videoUiWrapper thumbnail">
      <video width="100%" id="vdHotPress" controls>
        <!-- set width to 100% and add controls for play and volume buttons-->

        <source src="http://ia700305.us.archive.org/18/items/CopyingIsNotTheft/CINT_Nik_H264_720.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <source src="http://ia700305.us.archive.org/18/items/CopyingIsNotTheft/CINT_Nik_H264_720_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can go here to learn more about [HTML5 player options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video).

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the Op and further visitors, when you add some explanation to your intension. You can do that by using the 'edit' link underneath your post.